# MPMoviePlayerController "thumbnailImageAtTime:timeOption:" selector does not exist

Tags: objective-c, iphone

This code

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController* mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

    int i=0;
    unsigned int mc = 0;
    Method * mlist = class_copyMethodList(object_getClass([mp moviePlayer]), &mc);
    NSLog(@"%d methods", mc);
    for(i=0;i<mc;i++)
        NSLog(@"Method no #%d: %s", i, sel_getName(method_getName(mlist[i])));
    /* note mlist needs to be freed */

    if  ([[mp moviePlayer] respondsToSelector:@selector(thumbnailImageAtTime:timeOption:)])
    {
        image = [[mp moviePlayer] thumbnailImageAtTime:(NSTimeInterval)2.0 timeOption: MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
    }
    [mp release];
```

print this Log

45 methods

Method no #0: pause

Method no #1: stop

Method no #2: initialPlaybackTime

Method no #3: setInitialPlaybackTime:

Method no #4: scalingMode

Method no #5: setScalingMode:

Method no #6: contentURL

Method no #7: initWithContentURL:

Method no #8: movieSourceType

Method no #9: setMovieSourceType:

Method no #10: movieMediaTypes

Method no #11: prepareToPlay

Method no #12: isPreparedToPlay

Method no #13: isFullscreen

Method no #14: setUseApplicationAudioSession:

Method no #15: shouldAutoplay

Method no #16: setShouldAutoplay:

Method no #17: controlStyle

Method no #18: setControlStyle:

Method no #19: setContentURL:

Method no #20: setFullscreen:animated:

Method no #21: useApplicationAudioSession

Method no #22: playableDuration

Method no #23: setEndPlaybackTime:

Method no #24: endPlaybackTime

Method no #25: loadState

Method no #26: dealloc

Method no #27: view

Method no #28: init

Method no #29: forwardInvocation:

Method no #30: backgroundView

Method no #31: methodSignatureForSelector:

Method no #32: duration

Method no #33: play

Method no #34: setRepeatMode:

Method no #35: playbackState

Method no #36: setFullscreen:

Method no #37: naturalSize

Method no #38: skipToBeginning

Method no #39: repeatMode

Method no #40: beginSeekingBackward

Method no #41: beginSeekingForward

Method no #42: endSeeking

Method no #43: skipToNextItem

Method no #44: skipToPreviousItem

There is no any of thumbnail selectors.

Who know reason of this strange behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objective-C has multiple-level dispatch, so it's possible that the method you're interested in is implemented lazily or by forwarding. To see if it's lazily resolved, just move your loop to *after* you call the method.

While the above is all true, the method you're looking for is on [MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/MPMoviePlayerController), not MPMoviePlayerViewController.

Comment: The same. Without checking "respondsToSelector" program receives SIGABRT. So, mb exist some way to activate this "lazy" methods?